# ios crash in splunk mint

Tags: ios, crash, splunk

I've recently started getting these crashes frequently. But unable to figure out what does it really mean. It seems like the crash occured in MintRequestWorker. But this log is insufficient to know about it.

I am using `AFNetworking`, `Splunk Mint`, `Crashlytics`, `Google Analytics`.

Can someone guide me what am I probably doing wrong here?

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.root.default-priority
0  IOKit                          0x30bc831c IOServiceAddInterestNotification + 47
1  UIKit                          0x32950af1 _MatchedBatteries + 76
2  UIKit                          0x32950af1 _MatchedBatteries + 76
3  UIKit                          0x32950a2f -[UIDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:] + 198
4  Earthmiles                     0x001a268f -[DataFixture appendBaseValues] + 1652367
5  Earthmiles                     0x001a1f53 -[DataFixture init] + 1650515
6  Earthmiles                     0x001ce939 -[EventDataFixture init] + 1833273
7  Earthmiles                     0x001ca657 +[GnipDataFixture getInstanceWithAppEnvironment:] + 1816151
8  Earthmiles                     0x001db0e9 -[MintRequestJsonSerializer serializeEventToJsonForGnipWithAppEnvironment:] + 1884393
9  Earthmiles                     0x001a964d -[MintRequestWorker logEvent:] + 1680973
10 Earthmiles                     0x001ab19b -[MintRequestWorker closeSession] + 1687963
11 Earthmiles                     0x001ab51d __58-[MintRequestWorker closeSessionAsyncWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke + 1688861
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x3ab5bd53 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x3ab61689 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 228
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x3ab618dd _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3ac8cc17 _pthread_wqthread + 298
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3ac8cadc start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: Can you send an email to mobilesupport@splunk.com with some additional details? That will go directly to the MINT team